# Upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10

Tags: 15.10

Upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10 but on reboot my video is not coming up. I am using a AMD Radeon HD 8200/R3 series.

Comment: Your video is not coming up? Please clarify. This is vey un-specific

Comment: Install AMD driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMD Catalyst driver is having issues to work with kernel 4.2.

Reference : [A Fix For AMD Catalyst On Ubuntu 15.10 Is Coming](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-15.10-fglrx-Fix).

As a workaround uninstall the AMD proprietary drivers meanwhile.

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx
```

There is a workaround fix in wily-proposed but it is recommended to wait until it is tested.

Use the open source radeon drivers in the meantime until the final Catalyst fix is released.

Note :

In case you are experiencing problems to do this from the desktop you can use a virtual console.

From login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute the command.

Comment: Might be a good idea to also include the steps on doing this from a tty1 (i would assume problems with "video" means not getting a desktop ;) )